# How would I pass data from a POST request?

Tags: php, c, http, post

I have been building an HTTP Server (in the C programming language), and I'm wondering what would handle a POST request sent by a client. That is, if a client sends me a POST request to a PHP page, then how would I pass the data sent by the client to the PHP page?

Feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something needs to parse, compile and execute the PHP page. You're not about to write your own, so your server will need to act as a proxy for the request.

Solution 1: Setup a FastCGI PHP daemon. Your web server can then forward the request to PHP using the FastCGI protocol.

Solution 2: Setup a web server capable of handling PHP requests. Your web server can then (indirectly) forward the request to PHP using HTTP or HTTPS. This is less work for you, but it begs the question why you're not just using that web server throughout.

Comment: how fast is FastCGI?

Comment: Re "*how fast is FastCGI?*", As opposed to what?